# What is the predefined focus() function that is available in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, predefined-variables

Today I run into something unexpected when writing JavaScript in Chrome (version 37). It appears Chrome has a predefined `focus` variable available as a global. Upon further inspection via developer tools, I've found that this variable is a function:

```
> typeof focus
"function"
```

Does anyone know what this function is or does, or why is it a global?

I had a variable named `focus` and this global messed everything up in my webapp. I spent the last hour debugging where `focus` was getting created and it turned out that Chrome had it predefined.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about

[window.focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.focus)

> Makes a request to bring the window to the front. It may fail due to user settings and the window isn't guaranteed to be frontmost before this method returns.

It is a built-in function, not a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) but like `open` not a good name for a variable.
Other baddie is naming your submit button `submit` and then trying to submit the form programatically

Any variable defined in global scope may mess with other `window.xxxx` vars/functions.

[More window functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).